# What happens if Facebook rejects my app review?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We have an existing website and an existing (already approved) Facebook app that we use for sign ins and such. Everything is working great right now, but we would like to add some new open graph stories to our app - which requires us to submit the app for review again. Reading through their text it says that they are not only going to review the changes to the Facebook app, but also look at our website again. This is a cause for concern because we have a lot of daily users but we have no idea what the consequences would be if our Facebook app gets rejected. Would they simply not allow the new version? Would they completely disable our Facebook login?

In short: For an existing (and approved) Facebook app, what are the consequences for an update being rejected?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to submit permissions or actions for review again, Facebook is likely to only test and review those. They need to look at the app / website to determine how the permissions / actions are used and whether they comply with the Platform Policies.

Facebook will likely only approve / reject those permission / actions that you've submitted for review. However, if the behaviour of your older permission / actions have changed since they were last review and no longer comply with the Platform Policies, Facebook could revoke them too.

Before you submit your new permissions / actions for review, you should double check that all existing permissions and actions conform to the Platform Policies.

Comment: Overall this answer is correct, everything what worked before and has been approved before will stay the same. If there are problems with the newly submitted permissions/story types they just reject the new submission but not take away already approved ones.